# Deleting the second last row from Mysql(Mariadb) database

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, limit, sql-delete

So I can get the second last row from my database using

```
select* from hot_coffee_order order by OID desc limit 1,1
```

However when I try to delete this row using:

```
delete from hot_coffee_order order by OID desc limit 1,1
```

I encounter an error for some reason. Is there a way to delete the second last row from my database?

Comment: Why do you say "for some reason"? Isn't it obvious from the syntax in the documentation? The `LIMIT` clause in `DELETE` only allows you to specify a row count, not offset. It's not the same as `SELECT`.

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more complicated, but assuming that `OID` is unique, you can use a `join`:

```
delete hco
    from hot_coffee_order hco join
         (select hco2.*
          from hot_coffee_order hco2
          order by oid desc
          limit 1, 1
         ) hco2
         using (oid);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a reason why its much more complicated to delete the second last compared to the last one?

Comment: @ChrisCross . . . Well, `delete` doesn't support `offset`.